# https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone= is showing error

Tags: python-3.x, api, selenium, automation, whatsapp

```
for x in new:
    
    
    try:
        driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone={}'.format(x))
        time.sleep(30)
        msg_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@title='Type a message']")
        msg_box.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        
        for i in range(count):
            #msg_box.send_keys(Message[i])#time.sleep(2)
            #print(Message)
            #button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@class='tvf2evcx oq44ahr5 lb5m6g5c svlsagor p2rjqpw5 epia9gcq']")
            #button.click()
            time.sleep(5)
    except:
       continue
```

Hi. The code I have written is working perfectly for most part. But it is showing the message "The phone number shared via url is invalid" for some cases. But those are perfectly valid numbers. There is no particular pattern or particular type of numbers. It just randomly shows this error and starts working properly. What is the issue?

Comment: its working for me, the phone number you are using must not be present on whatsapp

Comment: Can you try for like 20 or 30 numbers? If you want I can give the entire code. Out of 20 numbers I stored atleast 2 gives the error

Comment: https://github.com/Mageshcoding/automatic-whatsapp-messages I have shared the link to the full code.

Comment: difficult to help until I see few data from `pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel("saved_file2.xlsx"))`

Comment: I have added the excel sheet in the github repository.

Comment: in this xlsx for what numbers is whatsapp showing invalid?

Comment: There is no particular pattern. The error is random. Atleast it is showing error for 2 of the numbers lets say 5th and 6th. I am pretty sure those whatsapp numbers exist. Since if I manually type the https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone="number" it is working.

Comment: @Priceofcoding I just tried them all manually and those are indeed invalid numbers

Comment: `https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+919*****288*
https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+917*****494*
https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+918*****144*
https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+919*****144*
https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+929*****892*
https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+930*****439*`

Comment: Thanks for trying out the code. If you mean the numbers are invalid why is the number working when I put it manually like "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+919*****288*". If you paste this number its taking you to the whatsapp number page. Or you meant there was an error in my code?